# Facing issue to Insert data into table in which column name start with number using python and 'INSERT' query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, insert, executemany

I am facing problem to insert pandas dataframe into Postgres table, here column name starting with Number like this - 03APH13W04D001.  table contains 72 such field , out of that I want to insert dataframe  in only 6 columns. Dataframe column length is 6.
This is my code :

```
 table='uaq_sec13_stream03'
 # dataframe = df13_03_00_00
 tpls = [tuple(x) for x in df13_03_00_00.to_numpy()] 
 cols = ','.join(list(df13_03_00_00.columns))
 sql = "INSERT INTO %s(date_time,'03APH13W04D001','03AOR13W04D001','03ATU13W04D001','03ACT13W04D001','03TIT13W04D001') VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)" % (table, cols)
 cur.executemany(sql, tpls)
```

Now I have chnaged thge querystring.
`sql = """INSERT INTO %s(date_time,"03APH13W04D001","03AOR13W04D001","03ATU13W04D001","03ACT13W04D00","03TIT13W04D001") VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)""" % (table, cols)`

> Now I am getting this error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> Error :
> psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "03"
> LINE 1: INSERT INTO uaq_sec13_stream03(date_time,03APH13W04D001,03AO...

Comment: Column names starting with a digit must be double-quoted. Using python heredoc syntax   `sql = """INSERT INTO %s(date_time, "03APH13W04D001", "03AOR13W04D001", ..."""`

Comment: Two things 1) Do not use Python string interpolation(%). It is a big SQL injection issue. See here [Query parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Using correct parameters will also properly escape/quote data values. 2) If you used the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)  module to build the query string the quoting would be done correctly for you.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm. Please do not encourage the use of string interpolation to build query strings.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I cannot but agree.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I have quoted column name with double quote , but now getting type Error